# calling a function in another class if using "namespace and use" in PHP

Tags: php

I know I can call the method in a class A into class B.  But I want to know if I use namespace for calling functions in another class instead.

```
namespace tiger
use cat;

class liger{

public $abc;

public function roar(){
 return $this->abc->purr();

} 

}

// calling the class n the function

$zyx = new liger();
$zyx->roar();   // output blank page....



class cat{
 public function purr();
  echo "I want to purrrr..!!!!!";
}

 ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
 ini_set('display_errors',1);
 error_reporting(-1);
```

OKAY  I TRIED Error reporting but its still a blank page.

Comment: Enable error reporting. This has nothing to do with namespaces, but with a property that is not an object.

Answer (score 0):

As @PeeHaa says in comment this has nothing to do with namespaces here..You are using the class like

```
class cat()
```

It must be like `class cat { }`